# Why does copying the rendered div change styling of the sub-divs when I paste it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a basic HTML+CSS+JS page that takes in some user details as a form and then creates an email signature for them. But when i paste the copied signature which is copied to clipboard after clicking the copy signature button, the pasted signature has all div elements stacked vertically whereas if you see the rendered html page you'll see that the "logo-container" has img and "text-container" elements next to each other. You can check it out in the 2 pictures posted in the end where the user details that should be adjacent to the image go below it in the email client. Why could that be happening?

Here's my `index.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Email Signature Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="fill-info-container">
        <div id="fill-info-top-banner" class="banner-container">
          <img
            src="Signature_assets\Signature_assets\signatur_logo_png.png"
            alt="Main logo"
            class="logo"
          />
          <p class="title">Email Signature generator</p>
        </div>
        <form id="info-form">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="full-name"
            id="full-name"
            placeholder="Full Name"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            id="title"
            placeholder="Title"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="phone-number"
            id="phone-number"
            placeholder="Phone Number"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            required
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="linkedin"
            id="linkedin"
            placeholder="LinkedIn URL"
          />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="book-a-call"
            id="book-a-call"
            placeholder="Book a Call URL"
          />

          <div class="country-buttons">
            <input
              type="radio"
              id="denmark"
              name="country"
              value="Denmark"
              required
              checked
            />
            <span class="radioLabel">Denmark</span>

            <input
              type="radio"
              id="norway"
              name="country"
              value="Norway"
              required
            />
            <span class="radioLabel">Norway</span>

            <input
              type="radio"
              id="sweden"
              name="country"
              value="Sweden"
              required
            />
            <span class="radioLabel">Sweden</span>
          </div>

          <button type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div id="signature-preview-container">
        <p>Preview</p>
        <div id="preview-card">
          <div class="logo-container">
            <img
              src="signature_logo_png.png"
              alt="Preview Card Logo"
            />
            <div class="text-container">
              <p>[Full name]</p>
              <p>[Title]</p>
              <p>[Phone number] | [E-mail address]</p>
              <p>www.mycompany.co | LinkedIn | Book a Call</p>
              <p>Odense Oslo Goteborg</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <img
            src="signature_banner.png"
            alt="Logo Image Long"
            class="banner-image"
          />
          <p class="tc-text">
            This email is sent from My company, which is part of the global group
            my company, which operates through several separate legal entities.
            <br />
            <br />
            The content of this email is confidential and intended for the
            recipient specified in the message only. It is strictly forbidden to
            share any part of this message with any third party, without written
            consent from the sender. All quotation requests are sent to compare
            available offers and do not imply entering into a legally binding
            contract. If you received this message by mistake, please reply to
            this message and follow with its deletion, so that we can ensure
            such a mistake does not occur in the future.
          </p>
        </div>
        <p class="instruction-text">
          Click on the button below. Go to Outlook -> Settings -> E-mail
          signatures. Create a new signature. Now press ctrl+v or cmd+v on Mac.
          That's it.
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="copy-button">Copy Signature</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my style.css

```
/* CSS styling for inter-div display */

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-top: 100px;
  max-width: 800px; /* Set the maximum width for the container */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container on the page */
}

#fill-info-container,
#signature-preview-container {
  padding: 20px;
}

#fill-info-container {
  background-color: #f0f0f0; /* Set a background color for the first div */
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}

/* CSS for the info form */

#info-form input,
#info-form button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add some spacing between the stacked fields */
}

#info-form .country-buttons {
    display: flex;
    gap: 10px; /* Adjust the gap between radio buttons as needed */
  }

.banner-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 50px; /* Adjust the width of the image as needed */
  height: 50px; /* Adjust the height of the image as needed */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Add some spacing between the image and text */
}

/* CSS for the signature preview */
#signature-preview-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 1000%;
}

#signature-preview-container p {
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add some spacing between the paragraphs */
}

.logo-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* Adjust as needed */
}

.logo-container img {
  width: 100px; /* Adjust the width of the logo image as needed */
  height: auto; /* Allow height to adjust proportionally */
  margin-right: 10px; /* Add spacing between the logo and text */
}

.text-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100px; /* Limit the maximum height of the text container */
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide any overflowing text */
}

.text-container p {
  margin: 0; /* Remove any default margin on paragraphs */
  font-size: 10px; /* Adjust font size as needed */
}

.banner-image {
  width: 100%; /* Make the banner image span the entire width of the div */
}


.tc-text {
  margin: 0; /* Remove any default margin on paragraphs */
  font-size: 8px; /* Adjust font size as needed */
  word-wrap: break-word; /* Allow long words to break and wrap */
  max-width: 100%; /* Set the maximum width to be the width of the container */
}
.instruction-text {
  width: 100%; /* Make the banner image span the entire width of the div */
}

.copy-button {
  width: 100%; /* Make the banner image span the entire width of the div */
}
```

Here's my `script.js`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Function to display the generated signature
    function displayGeneratedSignature() {
        // Get the form values
        const fullName = document.getElementById('full-name').value;
        const title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        const phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone-number').value;
        const email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        const linkedin = document.getElementById('linkedin').value;
        const bookACall = document.getElementById('book-a-call').value;

        // Map the form values to the signature elements
        document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(1)').textContent = `${fullName}`;
        document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(2)').textContent = `${title}`;
        //   document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(3)').textContent = `${phoneNumber} | ${email}`;
        const emailLink = email ? `<a href="mailto:${email}">${email}</a>` : '';
        document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(3)').innerHTML = `${phoneNumber} | ${emailLink}`;
        const linkedinText = linkedin ? `<a href="${linkedin}" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>` : '';
        const bookACallText = bookACall ? `<a href="${bookACall}" target="_blank">Book a Call</a>` : '';

        if (linkedinText && bookACallText) {
            document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(4)').innerHTML = `www.mycompany.co | ${linkedinText} | ${bookACallText}`;
        } else if (linkedinText) {
            document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(4)').innerHTML = `www.mycompany.co | ${linkedinText}`;
        } else if (bookACallText) {
            document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(4)').innerHTML = `www.mycompany.co | ${bookACallText}`;
        } else {
            document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(4)').innerHTML = `www.mycompany.co`;
        }


        // Map the country to the city
        const cities = {
            Denmark: 'Odense',
            Norway: 'Oslo',
            Sweden: 'Goteborg'
        };

        const denmark_tc = 'Denmark T&C';

        const norway_tc = 'Norway T&C';

        const sweden_tc = 'Sweden T&C';

        const tcTexts = {
            Denmark: denmark_tc,
            Norway: norway_tc,
            Sweden: sweden_tc,
        };
        const selectedCountry = document.querySelector('input[name="country"]:checked').value;
        document.querySelector('.text-container p:nth-child(5)').textContent = cities[selectedCountry];
        document.querySelector('.tc-text').textContent = tcTexts[selectedCountry];
    }

    function copySignature() {
        var previewCard = document.getElementById('preview-card');

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(previewCard);
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);

        try {
            document.execCommand('copy');
            alert('Signature preview copied to clipboard!');
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('Unable to copy signature preview:', e);
        }

        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }

    const generateButton = document.getElementById('generate');
    generateButton.addEventListener('click', displayGeneratedSignature)

    // Add a click event listener to the "Copy Signature" button
    const copyButton = document.querySelector('.copy-button');
    copyButton.addEventListener('click', copySignature);
});
```

[image: How the signature is rendered properly on my page]

[image: How it looks when you paste it into the email client]

As shown above, I tried changing my css file and the way the divs are structured but it doesnt make sense to me. How is it that the copied div is different from the rendered div the line `var previewCard = document.getElementById('preview-card');` in function `copySignature` literally gets that same div by id! Where am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check what content is exactly being paste in the signature, you can check that here '%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures' (open this in Run(windows + r) dialog). There shuold be a .htm file that shows the exact html content. Apparantly outlook is doing some processing on pasted content.